# replace string with variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to replace the string **score20130901** with a variable (**flag.currentflag**) from mongodb:

```
var selected_book = Books.findOne({_id: book});  // works
var flag = Flags.findOne({_id: "bookflag"});  // flag.currentflag works
var tmpone = Flags.findOne({_id: "one"}); // works

if (selected_book.score20130901[tmpone.oneround] > 0)
```

I've tested all variables with alert(...); and I get the correct value from each variable. But If I replace score20130901 with flag.currentflag - it doesn't work.

**Error:**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Try this : selected_book[flag.currentflag][tmpone.oneround]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation `object.property` is equivalent to `object["property"]`.

Therefore you can use `selected_book[flag.currentflag]`, which will yield the same as `selected_book.score20130901`.